Issue using app.overrideredirect(True) in my CustomTkinter application
I'm using app.overrideredirect(True) in my customtkinter application to create a custom title bar. However, the application doesn't appear in the Windows taskbar. When I click outside the app, it disappears completely and I can't bring it back with Alt+Tab or Windows+Tab
from customtkinter import *


app = CTk()
app.geometry("350x500")
app.title("WHC Launcher | Sign In")
app.overrideredirect(True)
app.iconbitmap("WHC.ico")
app.wm_attributes("-toolwindow", False)


minimize_button = CTkButton(app, text="−", font=("Arial", 20), width=30, height=30, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent", hover_color="#333333", command=lambda: app.withdraw())
minimize_button.place(x=270, y=10)

close_button = CTkButton(app, text="✕",  font=("Arial", 18), width=30, height=30, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent", hover_color="#FF0000", command=app.destroy)
close_button.place(x=305, y=10)

app.mainloop()

Tried creating a "Dummy Window"(invisible window) which acts as the main application window, as ChatGPT suggested, but still didn't work.
root = CTk() root.withdraw()  # Hide the root window  

It literally didn't change anything

For Windows 10 or 11 platform, you can try the module hPyT to hide the title bar and keep the icon in the taskbar:
import customtkinter as ctk
import hPyT

app = ctk.CTk()
hPyT.title_bar.hide(app)
...

Result:


PS: Suggest to use app.iconify instead of app.withdraw to minimize the window.

Works, thanks! As for the app.iconify, I didn't even knew it existed. Thanks for both answers, works flawlessly
